If the suprema of a decreasing sequence converges or goes to $+\infty$ then there is a subsequence converge to the limit of suprema or $+\infty$
I have difficulties convincing myself if the following statement is valid:

Let $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence. For each $n$, define $\beta_n$ by letting $\beta_n = \{\alpha_n,\alpha_{n+1},\dots\}$. Then $\{\sup \beta_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ forms a decreasing sequence. Suppose that $\sup \beta_n \to \gamma$, where $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}\bigcup\{+\infty\}$. Then there must be a subsequence $\{\alpha_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\alpha_{n_k}\to\gamma$.

This is what I have tried so far. I want to prove it for each of the case $\gamma=+\infty$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ by contradiction.

Suppose that $\gamma=+\infty$. Assume to the contrary that no subsequence $\{\alpha_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of $\{\alpha_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ satisfies $\alpha_{n_k}\to+\infty$. Since $\sup \beta_n \geq \sup \beta_{n+1}$ for all $n$, it follows that $\sup \beta_n = +\infty$ for all $n$; in particular, $\sup \beta_1 = \sup\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots\} = +\infty$. However, our assumption implies that there must be an upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$ for every $\{\alpha_{n_k},\alpha_{n_{k+1}},\dots\}$; in particular, there must be an upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$ for $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots\}$, a contradiction.

Is this correct?
Moreover, I couldn't figure out how to proceed for the case when $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$. Could someone please help me out?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Your proof for the $\infty$ case is correct.
Regarding the finite limit case, I would suggest a direct approach rather than looking for a contradiction.
Specifically, suppose $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$. As $\{\sup \beta_n\}_{n\geq 1}$  converges to $\gamma$, there exists some $n_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that  $$\gamma-1< \sup \beta_n < \gamma+1$$ for all $n\geq n_1$; in particular, this is valid for $n_1$. Thus, we find there is some $m_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m_1\geq n_1$ and $\gamma-1<a_{m_1}<\gamma+1$ (if the supremum of all the $a_i$'s is between $\gamma-1$ and $\gamma+1$ then there must be some $a_i$ in that interval too).
Analogously, there exists some $n_2\in\mathbb{N}$, that we may take bigger than $m_1$, such that $$\gamma-1/2< \sup \beta_n < \gamma+1/2$$ for all $n\geq n_2$. Thus, there exists some $m_2\geq n_2$ (and consequently bigger than $m_1$) such that $\gamma-1/2<a_{m_2}<\gamma+1/2$.
Defining $\{a_{m_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ recursively, we find by construction it is a subsequence that converges to $\gamma$.
